# Construction of a Turing Machine that accepts the language of (a^nb^nc^md^m for) m,n >= 1

Tags: turing-machines, context-free

i recently have been practicing constructing Turing Machines for languages. But i can't seem to figure this one out. I've seen a few videos on constructing 3 equal length strings (a^nb^nc^n) But i can't figure out this one. Can anyone help out how i can do this. Please don't give the answer outright, i want to actually know how it works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Really, you have two identical tasks concatenated. Read the $a$'s and $b$'s and see if they're in the right form. Then, more or less reset and do the same things for the $c$'s and $d$'s. BTW, Welcome to the site!